# Treat Entity with Id NULL as NEW

Tags: javers

To the question "Save Differences with Entity ID" I found the following answer:

"For Entities, Id property cannot be null, so you need to map this class as ValueObject. If so, 
Id property is treated as regular property and it not goes to GlobalId of this object."

My question is:

Why can't an entity be treated as NEW if the Id is NULL?

I have an object graph that is fetched from the database, and between two javers commits an entity is added to a list in the graph.

1. Two commits and in the second commit there is a new entity (Id NULL)
2. Get the change => exeption because Javers can't create a GlobalId.

I can get arround this by doing EntityManager - persist (creates Id:s), but I would like to avoid doing that. The present code may do a persist later or it just lets the transaction finish.

Because the Id is NULL, the entity is NEW. Would it be possible to generate a unigue temp Id (allow Id = NULL) to be able to create the GlobalId?
In the change list, the entity would be reported as NEW. No need to compare with earlier commits.

Answer (score 1):

You should compare/commit your objects when they are fully initialized so when they have Ids.

An entity without Id can't be handled by JaVers for several reasons:

- it can't be compared to other entity/version (diff algorithm is based on GlobalIds)
- it can't be queried from JaVersRepository (queries use GlobalIds)

If you are using Hibernate, compare/commit your new objects after Hibernate assigns them Ids from sequences.

Another options:

- don't use sequence-generated values as JaVers Id but some business identifiers
- if an Entity doesn't have a business identifier you can generate UUID in a constructor and use it as JaVers id (and also database PK if you like)